# Cant remove two horizontal black bars on iPhone 4 app

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin

I am developing an application for iOS with Xamarin Studio and when I try the app out on my iPhone and in the simulator, there are two horizontal bars at the top and bottom when the device is tilted in landscape orientation. I've seen some people have said that you need to add a launch image and name it `Default-568h@2x`, but that doesn't solve my problem.

Also I tried deleting and resetting content on the simulator and cleaned my project. Usually I see posts about the iPhone5 letter-boxing causing problem for some people, but for me it's the iPhone4 and 4s which is causing the problem. Anyone have any other ideas on what might be the problem?

[image: Image of how it looks:]

Comment: these are called horizontal lines not vertical lines...

Comment: On iPhone 5 simulator it looks good?

Answer (score 0):

You're using the iPhone 4 simulator. The image is being resized with fixed aspect, thus the letterboxing. Did you include a 640x960 Default@2x.png launch image?

Comment: Yes, I have added a 640x960 Default@2x.png and still nothing.